# calling bash command in python

Tags: bash, scripts, python

i called bash command in python in subprocess.call, and the return should be a number for example 3, and in the output, it gives the number as output, but it doesn't put it in the variables for example, the variable y here is still =0 
x is the shell command

```
y=subprocess.call(x,shell=True))
print "this is y",y
```

the output is

```
3
this is y 0
```

I need to use the return 3 in my script, but i can't use it because y still return value 0, any idea how to put the returned value in a variable

Comment: "Nothing is new under the sun ! " http://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/3701431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

The zero means the command ran successfully (else it would be `1`)

I guess this is what you wanted:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
a=["wc", "-l", "file.txt"]
y = subprocess.check_output(a).decode("utf-8").strip()
print(y)
```

With output:

```
35 file.txt
```

Comment: that worked fine for a simple command, but for complicated command like this
echo "'show stat'" | socat unix-connect:/var/run/haproxy/admin.sock stdio | grep webservers | wc -l
it gives an error, how is it possible to splitt the command ?

Comment: @Adam all can be done, but I would switch to using built-in tools from python where you can.

Comment: I am quite new to python, so not so familiar yet with built-in tools